# Notation for multiple summation for two functions

Tags: functions, summation, notation

Suppose I have two functions, namely $f_1(x_i)$ and $f_2(x_i)$. In addition, I also have $n$ numbers of $x$ (i.e., $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$). Is there an alternate way to represent the multiple summations given below?

$$
\sum_{i_n=1}^{2}...\sum_{i_2=1}^{2}\sum_{i_1=1}^{2}{f_{i_1}(x_1)\cdot f_{i_2}(x_2) ... f_{i_n}(x_n)} 
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum over $n$-uples of $1$'s and $2$'s:

$$
\sum_{i \in \{1,2\}^n} f_{i_1}(x_1) \cdot \ldots \cdot f_{i_n}(x_n)
$$

Comment: How about the multiplicative of the functions inside the sum notation? Can I use the product notation phi?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can further shorten this by writing
$$
\sum_{i \in \{1,2\}^n} \prod_{j=1}^{n} f_{i_j} (x_j)
$$
but maybe this may be hard to read for some.

Comment: Great! Thank you for clarifying